# Least optimization derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

C. J. Pennycuick in his article, "The Mechanics of Bird Migration" (Ibis, 111, pp.525-556, 1969), determined the following formula for the power power(v) which a bird has to maintain to fly at speed v :

$$\text{power}(v) = \dfrac{w^2}{2 d S v} + \tfrac12 d A v^3$$

​Here $d$ is air density, $w$ is the weight of the bird, and $S$ and $A$ are certain parameters connected with the bird's shape and size.
Use the derivative power$'(v)$ to determine a formula for velocity $v$ that makes power$(v)$ as small as possible. ​

So far, I have gotten the value of $v$, for power$'(v)$ when power'$(v)=0$. Will plugging in the negative solution from power$'(v)=0$ to power$(v)$ be enough to solve this problem?

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: I've never heard of mathjax

Comment: Here is some info. on MathJax, a markup language so people can read your question without too much difficulty: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The answer is "yes".

Comment: You also need to check that the result corresponds to a minimum (second derivative must be positive).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici (bonjour!) You are right. We can advise "sfewr" to draw a graphical representation of function "power". It makes things so more concrete !

Comment: @JeanMarie. Nice to see you here ! It is a good idea, for sure.